# storing messages with a discord bot

Tags: discord.py, python-decorators

I'm trying to store messages with a discord bot, so that I can learn how the elements of messages vary between messages.

However i am new to some aspects of this coding- i.e. decorators. Currently the piece of my bots code that interacts with messages is this:

```
messages=[]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message,messages):
    print("someone said something")
    messages=messages+message
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return messages
```

I think this is wrong. What I am trying to do is add a message to messages each time the event happens, so that I can later go through that variable and see how the different elements of messages change.

How do i change the above to allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only 1 parameter in `on_message` event. Also, you can't append things to a list with `+`. And Also storing data in variable is not a good idea because whenever you restart the bot, it'll be deleted. You can simply store them in a txt file.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("someone said something")
    file = open('messages.txt', 'a')
    file.write(message.content + '\n')
    file.close()
```

**EDIT**

If you want to store all the information of the message, you can do:

```
file.write(f'{message}\n')
```

or

```
file.write(str(message) + '\n')
```

Comment: thanks!
is there a way of doing it so it saves all evelemts of message not just .content?

Comment: Why do you want it to save all elements?

Comment: Because I am trying to see how they vary between messages